# Send a sign-out request B2C what happens

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

What is the functionality of the following api - [Send a sign-out request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-oidc#send-a-sign-out-request)

```
"GET https://fabrikamb2c.b2clogin.com/fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/logout?p=b2c_1_sign_in&post_logout_redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Faadb2cplayground.azurewebsites.net%2F"
```

My understanding is the refresh token is not revoked. Only Refresh token is removed from the local storage.  Then why is a server request required. What value does it add?  How does the api know which user session to logout?

Answer (score 0):

> My understanding is the refresh token is not revoked. Only Refresh
>   token is removed from the local storage.

It's not related to the refresh token. It is just to fully clear your app's cookies or otherwise end the session with the user by redirecting the user to Azure AD to sign out. Because if you fail to do so, the user might be able to reauthenticate to your app without entering their credentials again.

Comment: in that case is it enough to clear the cookie ? Or on the sever side is there some session created.  While invoking the method how does it know which user session is referred ?

Comment: Usually, in this way, it is enough to clear the cookie.